# C type casting with "const" keyword

Tags: c++, c, casting, constants

I usually use C type casting in C/C++ code. My question is, does adding the "const" keyword in the casting type mean anything to the result?

For example, I can think up several scenarios:

```
const my_struct *func1()
{
   my_struct *my_ptr = new my_struct;

   // modify member variables

   return (const my_struct *)my_ptr;
   // return my_instance;
}
```

In this one, the function constructs a new instance of a struct, and casting it to to a constant pointer, therefore caller will not be able to further modify its internal state except deleting it. Is the "const" casting required, recommended, or simply unnecessary, since either return statement works.

In this one, `my_base` is the base class of `my_derive`.

```
const my_base *func2(const my_derive *my_ptr)
{
    return (const my_base *)my_ptr;
    // return (my_base *)my_ptr;
}
```

Since `my_ptr` is already a const pointer, would casting it with `(my_base *)` involve a const_cast for removing const and another implicit const_cast when returning?

Is there any reason to add "const" to an integer function argument, since changing it never affect state outside the function?

```
void func3(const int i)
{
    // i = 0; is not allowed, but why, as it is harmless?
}
```

How about adding "const" when casting an integer? I think this should resemble `func2()`.

```
void func4(short i)
{
    const unsigned int j = (const unsigned int) i;
    // const unsigned int j = (unsigned int) i;
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong. Considering type casting might be an FAQ, I'm not sure if this one duplicates with anything else. Thanks!

Comment: The question mentions "C/C++", which is a bad idea. Particularly so here, since while both C and C++ have a `const` keyword, its meaning is very different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the `const` keyword in the casting type means that the result will be constant. The following will not compile in C++ (in C it has no effect):

```
int* x = (const int*)malloc(10); // cannot convert from 'const int *' to 'int *'
```

You really shouldn't use C type casting in your **C++** code. It is not safe and should be used only for compatibility with the legacy C code. You should use C++ casts instead.

In cases as in `func3` usually `const` qualifier is not used. There's no big reason to add `const` qualifier to function argument if it has not pointer or not reference type. Consider the following:

```
void func3(      TYPE i);  // no reason to use `const`
void func3(const TYPE& i); // use `const`, so as not to accidentally change `i`
```

When you assign lvalue to rvalue, as in `func4`, there's no need to explicitly specify the `const` qualifier in the cast expression. Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion will be performed implicitly according to the C++ Standard 4.1.

Comment: The `malloc` example is interesting. On the contrary, this is OK even in C++: `int a = 0; int b = (const int) a;` I know it is not safe to use C casting in C++. I raise this question only mean to discuss about the correct usage of C casting, theoretically. I always use the const reference to minimize argument passing cost and to avoid NULL pointers. I can understand there might be implicit conversion when assignment happens. Is there extra cost if I miss the `const` in the parentheses?

Thanks!

Comment: Extra cost in terms of compile time or ... ?

Answer (score 6):

Adding `const` to a cast is just like adding `const` to any other type specifier --- the resulting object is `const`. what this means depends on the context. If you add `const` at the top level (e.g. `const int` or `const foo` or `int* const`, then you just have a `const` object. In most cases this can be copied and assigned just like a non-`const` object can (though there's a few exceptions, like `std::auto_ptr`).

If you add the `const` to a pointer then you can also add it to the pointed-to type. e.g. `int * const` is a `const` pointer to a plain `int`, whereas `const int*` or `int const*` is a plain pointer to a `const int`.

```
int i;
int* p = (int* const) &i; // fine; top-level const not a problem
int* p2 = (int const*) &i; // error; pointed-to object is const, so this is preserved
int const* p3= (int const*) &i; // OK
```

`const` at the top level in a parameter declaration is just like declaring any other local variable `const` --- you cannot modify the named object within the function body. However, this `const` does not form part of the function type, so you can forward-declare the function without it (with conforming compilers at least).

```
void func(int i); // forward-declare func
void func(const int i) // this matches the declaration
{
    // i is const here
}
```

This could be argued to be good style --- whether or not the variable is treated as `const` inside the function is an implementation detail so shouldn't be in the prototype. Within the definition, it follows the guideline of declaring something `const` if you don't intend to modify it.

Using `const` elsewhere in the parameter declaration (e.g. as part of a pointer) does affect the function type, as with the casts.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example returning non-const in a function that requires const will cat it again meaning that const matters, but you can't notice it because if it's not there it will be added.
In the second example it will be one cast maintaining const.
In third example it is disallowed because it is harmless: i will change for the rest of the function and unrecoverable.
Keep in mind that putting type into container not of it's type will cast it automaticllay same as int put in long field won't remain int.
You also have to remember that const means about the same as private or public to the assembler, which is nothing. The assembler code generated will not differ at all no matter where you put const and will run at same speed exacly.

Comment: Do you mean it is better to explicitly write "const" when casting to minimizing cost? For the function argument one, as *Anthony* mentioned, whether or not put the "const" is of the function implementer's concern, therefore I think the extra "const" will not cause problem when using external libraries. Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing to minimize, casting does nothing unless it has cast operator. All the casting is done at compile time for type safety. Only casting things like int to double or char* to std::string takes time, even casting in inheritance doesn't do anything. It's all for type safety and doesn't generate assembler code.